# JavaWeb com xhtml

Tags: jsf

Como eu posso fazer um menu para me digitar a data de nascimento para cadastrar um novo cadastro?

Meu código está assim:

```
    <!-- Nome -->
    <h:outputText value="Nome" />
    <h:inputText value="#{CadastroDados.nome}" />
    <br />

    <!-- Sobrenome -->
    <h:outputText value="Sobrenome" />
    <h:inputText value="#{CadastroDados.sobrenome}" />
    <br />      

    <!--  Sexo -->
    <h:selectOneRadio id="selectsexo" value="#{CadastroDados.sexo}">
        <l:selectItem id="item1" itemLabel="Masculino" itemValue="Masculino" />
        <l:selectItem id="item2" itemLabel="Feminino" itemValue="Feminino" />
    </h:selectOneRadio>
    <br />      

    <!-- Data de Nascimento --> 
            <!-- ... -->

    <!-- Execução -->
    <h:commandButton value="Verificar" action="#{CadastroDados.exe}" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Com JSF puro você pode usar:

```
<h:inputText value="#{cadastroDados.dataNascimento}">  
   <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>  
</h:inputText>
```

O `pattern` é o padrão de data esperado na entrada. Segue o padrão do `DateFormatter`. Se você usar padrão ISO, por exemplo, seria `yyyy-MM-dd`. Será renderizado um componente de entrada `<input>` comum.

Se você puder usar uma biblioteca de widgets como o [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org/), você pode usar o componente **[calendar](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/calendarHome.jsf)** que é bem mais simples e faz aparecer um calendário na página.

```
<p:calendar value="#{cadastroDados.dataNascimento}" />
```

(você terá que incluir o PrimeFaces no seu projeto e declarar o prefixo `p` (ou outro) com o namespace da biblioteca.)

Existe também a opção de usar HTML5 se você estiver usando JSF 2.2. Você precisará registrar um prefixo para o namespace do recurso chamado de "pass-through" (`pt` no exemplo abaixo) e prefixar os atributos do HTML5 no seu campo de entrada. Assim você poderá usar a renderização de calendário HTML5 suportada pelo browser e capturar seus dados de entrada:

```
<h:inputText value="#{cadastroDados.dataNascimento}" pt:type="date" />
```

Veja [8.9 HTML5-Friendly Markup](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsf-facelets009.htm)

Finalmente, há uma forma transparente de usar esses recursos através da inclusão de outra biblioteca, o [OmniFaces](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/). Veja um exemplo em [Adding HTML5 attributes to standard JSF components](http://balusc.blogspot.com.br/2012/06/adding-html5-attributes-to-standard-jsf.html).